# Is it possible to know if there is a VOIP call active in Android?

Tags: android, voip, voip-android

My app plays sounds on the device depending on different situations of a factory. I pay attention if the user is in a current call to not play anything using this code:

```
AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(amanager.getMode() == AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL) {
   //Don't play sound, user is speaking
   return;
}
```

I want to be able to know if the user is in a VoIP call, to avoid also playing anything and respecting the user.

I am not searching for any VoIP listener to control every step on incoming, outgoing, dialing, connecting or whatever. I just need a simple solution to know if the user is talking at this moment on the device (real call or Internet call). Thanks

Comment: I recommend that you worry about the [audio focus APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus.html) and less about the behaviors of specific app categories, like VOIP.

Comment: I must play those sounds even if the user is playing music or playing a game. I just want to avoid playing my sounds when there is a call (real call or VOIP call)

Comment: There is no requirement for a VOIP call to tell you that a VOIP call is going on. They *could* use `setMode()` on `AudioManager` to set the mode to `MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION`. However, that's very old, and Google has been steering developers to audio focus, so I would not be surprised if many VOIP apps only deal with that.

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Comment: No, I haven't. Sorry.